# Yap viewer getting slow

Tags: miktex, viewers, dvi

I switched recently from MikTeX 2.5 to MiKTeX 2.9 version for latex compilation. I'm getting the below issue with Yap viewer.

1. Performance of Yap viewer is very slow in opening and browsing through pages.
2. After each compilation, YAP viewer not showing the current opened page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: @Saravanan Please apologise the question: why don't you create a PDF? DVI as output seems only necessary in special cases (pstricks is the only one I know of).